# dropdown navigation bar with mysql results that also acts as a form to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a long one that all together is creating a few problems.

I have a navigation bar as follows:

```
<ul id="navigationbar">
        <li><a href="profile.php">$firstname</a></li>
        <li><a href="feed.php">feed</a></li>
        <li><a href="leagues.php">leagues</a></li>
        <li><a href="myTeams.php">teams</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="createnew.php">create</a></li>

        <form action="" id="findMyTeamsForm" method="POST">

        <li style="float:right"><input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." /></li>

        </form>

    </ul>
```

it works perfectly, all buttons navigate to certain pages and theres a search bar that is used to find users from a mysql search (code not shown).

What i would like to happen now, and which I'm struggling on, is when i click on 'teams', a mysql search gathers all the team names from that user and displays them as a dropdown list. Then when a team is clicked on, the page will redirect to 'myTeams.php' and display the correct team. Below is the code i have tried for all this and I've tried quite a few other things but I'm having no luck.

```
// query to find myteams for each user
  $findMyTeams = $pdo->prepare("SELECT teamName FROM teams WHERE username=?"); 

  $findMyTeams->execute([$username]);

    ($myTeams = $findMyTeams->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));



echo <<<_END


<!-- navigation bar setup-->    

    <ul id="navigationbar">
        <li><a href="profile.php">$firstname</a></li>
        <li><a href="feed.php">feed</a></li>
        <li><a href="leagues.php">leagues</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">teams</a>

        <ul id="myTeamList">

        <form action="myTeams.php" id="findMyTeamsForm" method="POST">

_END;

    foreach ($myTeams as $teamName) {
print  '<li><a href="myTeam.php?'.$teamName['teamName'].'">'.$teamName['teamName'].'</a> </li>'
    }


echo <<<_END

        </form>

            </ul> 

           </li>

        <li style="float:right"><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="create.php">create</a></li>


        <form action="" id="searchform" method="POST">

        <li style="float:right"><input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." /></li>

        </form>

    </ul> 

_END;
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you have the other closing `_END` identifier? it's not shown in your post. since we don't know if that is contributing to the problem here, or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing that out, it is in my code just not the question. I've added this in now

Comment: You're welcome. I had to be sure because some will most have likely posted an answer based on that; believe me when I say this *lol*, I've seen this happen quite often.

Comment: What does "_I've tried quite a few other things but I'm having no luck._" mean? Please explain what _having no luck_ means/what isn't working.